# How to debug nodejs forked process in Intellij

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

After my nodejs application started, I see the console output

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/my/index.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51650/19e65b0f-f9cb-41fd-89c6-1668ae0e6522
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
```

And, in my code, I'm forking a child process like this

```
    let worker = cluster.fork({
        worker_id: task._id,
        execArgv:['--inspect-brk']
    }).on('error', e => {
        error(prefix, 'error', e)
        finish(e)
    })
```

However, the following output is
`Error in JetBrains node debug connector: Failed to detect opened port`.

How can I enable the debug?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks related to [WEB-35630](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35630) and [WEB-36132](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36132), both are fixed in 2018.3.3.

If upgrading to 3.3 doesn't help, I'd suggest disabling `js.debugger.use.node.options` key in **Registry** ( **Help | Find action**, type `Registry` to locate it)